# Listening to WebSocket on ServerSide

Tags: php, websocket, phpwebsocket

I have a node.js server that creates a websocket that I listen to with JS on client side.
Is there a way to listen to the websocket connection using PHP on the Server Side?

Comment: You need to be a bit clearer mate Listen is what a server side process does. It listens for connection requests though not data.

Comment: In listen I mean that the websocket will send updates and the php script will catch them and act base on these updates

Comment: That's clearer. I don't know enough about the tech stacks to help, except to say a quick google websockets php and websockets node.js revealed a whole host of information which would have been my first port of call if I needed to learn for myself.

Comment: I don't know the answer either, but like Tony Hopkinson I felt like writing something anyway too. The question was clear though. Did you find an answer?